# I have server without console ssh, how Can I work with Magento?

Tags: magento2, server-setup

I have server without console ssh, how Can I work with Magento?
Work with XAMPP(with console) and upload (update) files to my server without console is right way?

Comment: It's depends on you that what you want we know that server can work without ssh for example we have Cpanel we can use it too but in my opinion ssh should be there reason behind this it makes your work faster i mean from development point of view we should use ssh not only it give us a fast environment it's also secure so i think use of ssh is batter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you don't have SSH access to the server but the SSH commands are allowed by the server.

In that case, I think **`system() function`** may help you.

To use this function, simply create a new file in the document root of the server (Let's call it **command.php**), then write below code in this file:

`system('php bin/magento cache:status');` // you can change it to your command

And run this script with http://your base url/command.php

It will give you the resulted output.

Comment: In my server are a lot of domains.  I need use command lines to 1 domain. 
I created command.php in  /domains/lismyexpage.com/public_html  and I write eg. system('php -v'); in this file and run lismyexpage.com/command.php but 'system('php -v');'  only this inscription showed on screen.

Comment: Sorry, i forget add <?php ?> Sorry.....   Works.

Comment: @Szolv, Can you please accept my answer if it helped?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot process without using ssh or shell.. If you are using magento2 there are commands to load in shell like 'upgrade or deploy or even cache clean or flush'. This time you have to use the shell command. Otherwise there is no chance to work with magento. Please go with only ssh console.

If you are using Windows system : You have to download putty and setup it.
If your system is Linux : Just go with terminal for Mac also you can use Terminal like ssh 'your user name and domain'

for more : https://opengear.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/216372563-Connecting-to-consoles-and-CLI-using-an-SSH-client

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/basics/basics_login.html

Hope this is what you looking for.